# How can I configure the WordPress development environment locally?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, web-developer-toolbar

Some third-party developers have created the sites and they were given to them for ongoing site maintenance such as editing posts, adding new posts, etc.

They just gave an WordPress administrator account. While I am logging into my account, it shows a lot of options to add/modify the page/post. How can I set the local development environment for my site and publish to the live site?

Can we do all the changes by using the online WordPress  administrator account itself or is there a limitation by doing it online?

Answer (score 0):

1. How can I set the local development environment for my site and publish to the live site? Download [the WordPress application from Bitnami](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/wordpress/)

2. Can we do all the changes by using the online WordPress administrator account itself or is there a limitation by doing it online? Yes you can do all the actions you need using the admin account, however, I would advise you create a user for yourself with the correct privileges for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Switch Case. Are you aware of how to get the code files can be downloaded from word press admin account which project files can be used for local set up.

Comment: I would unzip them into htdocs, you will have to create a local database in the way you would like but make sure WordPress is connected to it

Comment: How does that answer the question? Can you expand the answer (by [editing it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45251865/edit), not here in comments)? E.g., how is that application supposed to address the OP's concerns? Currently, it is not much more than a link-only answer.

Comment: @PeterMortensen this is 1. from 2017, 2. I have answer one of the two questions via this link. 

> How can I set the local development environment for my site and publish to the live site?

If you want an answer to the 2nd one, happy to. 

> Can we do all the changes by using the online WordPress administrator account itself or is there a limitation by doing it online? Yes you can do all the actions you need using the admin account, however, I would advise you create a user for yourself with the correct privileges for your needs.